# Proper method for creating splashscreen with drawImage(g)

Tags: java, awt, lifecycle, japplet

I'm learning to construct a JApplet, though as of yet haven't traveled far beneath the surface.  I have an image(.png) which would ideally be painted by paintComponent(s) before the interface is "painted" or rather added from within the paint() method.

Interestingly, the JApplet only loads as intended after it is cloned by the appletviewer.  It seems I'm missing understanding of the lifecycle, or operational dynamics otherwise.

Here's the code, from which the swing comp. definitions have been removed for brevity:

```
 public class JFriendsPhones extends JApplet implements ActionListener, MouseListener {  

public void init(){


    submit.addActionListener(this);
    queryByName.addActionListener(this);
    queryByNum.addActionListener(this);



    setVisible(true);

    introduction = getGraphics();

    prepareImage(intro, this);
    intro = getImage( getCodeBase(), "introduction.png");

    setVisible(true);

    validate();
}

public void start(){

}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    paintComponent(g);


    }


public void stop(){

}

public void destroy(){

}

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ev ){

    Object source = ev.getSource();

    returnLab.setVisible(false);
    resultsPan.setBackground(Color.white);

    if( true ){

        if( queryByName.getText().equals("") != true && queryByNum.getText().equals("") != true ){

                outcomeLab.setText("Search by only one term");
                queryByName.setText("");
                queryByNum.setText("");

        } else if( queryByName.getText().equals("") == true && queryByNum.getText().equals("") == true){
            outcomeLab.setText("Enter search term");

            } else {

                if(queryByName.getText().equals("") == false){

                    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
                        if(queryByName.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(friends[i])){
                            resultsPan.setBackground(new Color(190,255,200));
                            outcomeLab.setText("1-result found:");
                            returnLab.setText(frNumbers[i]);    
                            returnLab.setVisible(true);
                            found = true;
                        } 

                    } if(found == false){
                        resultsPan.setBackground(new Color(240,100,100));
                        outcomeLab.setText("0-matches");
                    }
                } else {

                    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){

                        if(queryByNum.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(frNumbers[i])){
                            resultsPan.setBackground(new Color(190,255,200));
                            outcomeLab.setText("1-result found:");
                            returnLab.setText(friends[i]);  
                            returnLab.setVisible(true);
                            found = true;
                        }                                       
                    }

                        if( found == false){
                                resultsPan.setBackground(new Color(240,100,100));
                                outcomeLab.setText("0-matches");
                        }

        }

              }
    }

    found = false;
}

public void componentResized( ComponentEvent cEv){
        repaint();
}

@Override
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        contain.repaint();

}

@Override
public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {

    paintComponent(introduction);

}

@Override
public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent clicked){
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics gr){

    super.paintComponents(gr);

    if(initialized == false){

        gr.drawImage(intro, 10, 10, 280, 430, this);
        validate();
            initialized = true;
        } else {

        titl_instrPan.add(titleLab);
        titl_instrPan.add(instructLab);
        titl_instrPan.add(instructLab2);

        inputPan.add(byNameLab);
        inputPan.add(queryByName);
        inputPan.add(byNumLab);
        inputPan.add(queryByNum);
        inputPan.add(regionPan);
        inputPan.add(submit);

        resultsPan.add(outcomeLab, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        resultsPan.add(returnLab, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        resultsPan.setBackground(Color.white);

        mainPanel.add(titl_instrPan, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(inputPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(resultsPan, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        contain.add(mainPanel);
        setVisible(true);
        validate();

        }


} end class JFriendsPhones
```

Comment: *"I'm learning to construct a JApplet"* Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Interesting.  The objections from the security issues and obsolescence of awt I agree with. Thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up the default painting mechanism of Swing by not invoking super.paint(...).

Anyway, don't override paint(..) of the JApplet!!! There is no need to do this.

Comment: I need to work on my problem solving skills under effects of fatigue, admittedly.  I've corrected this aspect of the program, but the behavior is virtually the same.  Cloning seems to contain a clue.

Comment: `I'm learning to construct a JApplet, though as of yet haven't traveled far beneath the surface` - so start with a JApplet that contains a single JLabel. Get that working. Then try two components on the Applet and get that working. Don't try to write a complete applet from scratch the first time. Keep the code simple so you can post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)  when you have a problem. Posting random bits of code doesn't help because until the problem is solved you don't know what code is or isn't relevant tot he problem.

Comment: Well, I did say that about JApplets, however I do have enough experience with Java to discern that definitions of components aren't relevant to the problem.  As I said, I resolved the issue by focusing on when the paint method is called.  Therefore there were no bits of random code because what was added included most of the Japplet class, the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the basics of the Graphics class, specifically 
    public void paint()
which is event-driven, I added a counter to the paint method to quickly learn how many times its called at startup, and used that number as the condition to execute the drawImage() method -- success.  An interesting note is that different compilers seem to vary in their initial calls to paint(), e.g., 5 by Eclipse's, 3 by javac 1.8.

Comment: This is the wrong solution. You should NOT override paint(...)!!! The structure of your applet is wrong.

Comment: Forgot to mention it's been changed to use paint()  itself.  Nothing's overriden in the current code.  Maybe you should go for a walk or something; find some way to relax.

Comment: `Forgot to mention it's been changed to use paint() itself.` you should never invoke paint() directly. You are the one asking the question. Learn how to problem solve and structure your code properly to avoid future problems. You even stated your get random number when using your approach.

Comment: You're really not listening.  JApplet's lifecycle includes event-driven calls to paint().  I placed my drawImage() method within this method, under the call to the super constructor.  The addition of JComponents to the GUI was transferred to the init() method.  Nothing's called directly, but paint(), as you recommended, is used as the method for drawing the "splash screen" within the main UI window.

Comment: No you are not listening. You stated. `I added a counter to the paint method to quickly learn how many times its called at startup, and used that number as the condition to execute the drawImage() method` - You should not override paint() and you should certainly not use a counter to determine when to do something. It is a hack that might work but will cause you problems in the future. You could just add a label containing the image to the appete, or you override the paintComponent() method of a JPanel and add the panel to the applet. Read the Swing tutorial.

Comment: Alright, I'll look at the current tutorials.  Is adding any code to the paint() method deprecated?  Aside from my class text, I've been reading an outdated Java How to Program 5th ed. text by Deitel & Deitel, in which they do add code to paint(), apparently overriding it, in examples of JApplet development.  Might be time to find a current D&D or something comparable.  Thanks for your help.